# Python np.arrays accessing indices with variable

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have an n dimensional numpy array A, and I have an index variable i=[x,y,z].

Normally, if I wanted to obtain the element of A at this index, I could just do A[x,y,z]. How would I do this if I only want to use A and i.

The reason I have to do this is because I do not know the dimension of A.

Comment: `A[tuple(i))]` applies the list

Comment: `A[x,y,z]` is equivalent to `A[(x,y,z)]`

Answer (score 0):

You could try looping through each element in the array `idx` to access a certain location within a given array `arr`.

```py
import numpy as np
d3 = np.zeros((4,4,4))
d3[3,1,2] = 12
d4 = np.zeros((4,4,4,4))
d4[2,1,2,1] = 24
d5 = np.zeros((4,4,4,4,4))
d5[2,3,1,0,1] = 36

def nDimensionalIndex(arr,idx):
    temp = arr
    for key in idx:
        temp = temp[key]
    return temp

print(nDimensionalIndex(d3,[3,1,2]))     # returns 12.0
print(nDimensionalIndex(d4,[2,1,2,1]))   # returns 24.0
print(nDimensionalIndex(d5,[2,3,1,0,1])) # returns 36.0
```

By using a temporary copy of the passed array, you can narrow down the dimensions of `temp` to find the value at `idx`. This allows you to get values within n-dimensional arrays.